# How Ignite Launch the ./libs customer Jar

Tags: deployment, jar, ignite

Need help, or give a link, or give a hint on this deployment,

Ignite Jar deployment case,

Say I have a jar package with the main-class defined, and put it into the ./libs folder, what will the ignite do, ignite how to launch this Jar? Which is the endpoint for Ignite launch this Jar?

Any specification for the Jar to the ./libs, btw , is there a full example of the userversion xml of ignite.xml, if put below content into the ignite.xml, ignite shows cannot recognize the userVersion tag,

```
<!-- User version. -->
<bean id="userVersion" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="0"/>
</bean>
```

my problem is don't know what ignite launch this Jar, I expect ignite can help launch the Jar main-class, and monitoring the cache put event, and it will fire the compute/tasks. And which is a loop forever.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite is not going to launch main-classes from JARs that you put to `libs/`. However, your code can be used from Apache Ignite APIs and elsewhere after you do that.